# Getting file download progress from POCO StreamCopier through HTTPS

Tags: c++, http, networking, https, poco-libraries

I have been working on HTTP clients using WinHTTP and WinInet and recently had a thought of switching to POCO as it offers  best APIs for HTTP implementations.

I did make it work, but the problem is that I want to know the download progress of the file either by querying the stream periodically or through some event handling.

Started searching for an API that can do this, then came across this [Http upload with progress info, in C++ (Poco/Boost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260056/http-upload-with-progress-info-in-c-poco-boost) that talks about getting the progress for file upload scenarios using CountingOutputStream. I feel that is incomplete and doesn't do that way I had expected, that doesn't use the actual implementation of that CountingStream at all.

I came to know that the implementation is possible through CountingInputStream but I don't know how to do that with the stream returned by HttpStreamFactory's open call. Is it possible to read the stream in multiple chunks using that? or query that periodically the amount of data read so that I can notify the UI?.

Here is my code:

```
bool HttpClientConnection::DownloadFile ( const std::string& file_url, const std::string file_location )
{

         try
         {
               std::string complete_page_url = "";
               std::ofstream file_stream;
               std::unique_ptr<std::istream> pStr       = nullptr;


               if (isSecureConnection)
               {
                    complete_page_url = "https://";
               }
               else
               {
                    complete_page_url = "http://";
               }


               {
                    complete_page_url = serverHostName + file_url;// assuming the file url itself will contain leading forward slash
               }


             // Create the URI from the URL to the file.
             URI uri(complete_page_url);

               //std::auto_ptr<std::istream>pStr(URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri);
            //StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), std::cout);

             if (isSecureConnection)
             {
                  std::unique_ptr<HTTPSStreamFactory> https_stream_factory = nullptr;

                  if (_buseProxy)
                  {
                       https_stream_factory = std::unique_ptr<HTTPSStreamFactory>(new HTTPSStreamFactory(proxyHostName, proxyPort, getProxyUserName(),  getProxyPassword()));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                       https_stream_factory = std::unique_ptr<HTTPSStreamFactory>(new HTTPSStreamFactory());
                  }

                  if (https_stream_factory)
                  {
                      pStr  = std::unique_ptr<std::istream>(https_stream_factory->open(uri));
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  std::unique_ptr<HTTPStreamFactory> http_stream_factory = nullptr;

                  if (_buseProxy)
                  {
                      http_stream_factory = std::unique_ptr<HTTPStreamFactory>(new HTTPStreamFactory(proxyHostName, proxyPort, getProxyUserName(),  getProxyPassword()));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      http_stream_factory   = std::unique_ptr<HTTPStreamFactory>(new HTTPStreamFactory());
                  }

                  if (http_stream_factory)
                  {
                      pStr  = std::unique_ptr<std::istream>(http_stream_factory->open(uri));
                  }
            }

            if (pStr)
            {
                  file_stream.open(file_location, ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);

                  StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), file_stream);

                  file_stream.close();
             }

           return true;
}
catch (Exception& exc)
{
    if (httpLogger)
    {
                                         httpLogger->log(dcLogger::LOG_INFO, "HttpClient:: Exception in DownloadFile , error code: %d", exc.code());
    }
}

return false;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passed the fileoutput stream object to CountingOutputStream and started a timer with the counting output stream as the parameter. The Timer is invoked periodically until the data transmission is complete that gets the count of bytes written and notifies the one who registered for that event. That worked!.

```
shared_ptr<CountingOutputStream> cout_stream = shared_ptr<CountingOutputStream>(new CountingOutputStream(file_stream));

if (callback && callback_interval_in_millis > 0)
{
    shared_ptr<FileProgressHandler> file_progress = shared_ptr<FileProgressHandler>(new FileProgressHandler(cout_stream, file_size, callback));

    if (file_progress)
    {
        TimerCallback<FileProgressHandler> callback(*(file_progress.get()), &FileProgressHandler::onTimer);

        timer = shared_ptr<Timer>(new Timer(0, callback_interval_in_millis));

        if (timer)
        {
            timer->start(callback);
        }
    }

    StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), *cout_stream);

    if (timer)
    {
         timer->stop();
    }
}

void onTimer(Timer& timer)
{
    try
    {
        if (progress_callback)
        {
            int data_processed = 0;

            counting_io_stream ? data_processed = counting_io_stream->chars() : __noop;

            if (data_processed != total_processed_data)
            {
                total_processed_data = data_processed;

                int percent     = (100 * total_processed_data) / file_size;

                progress_callback(percent);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(const std::bad_function_call& e) 
    {

    }
    catch(const std::bad_weak_ptr& e)
    {

    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure when `TaskManager` was released but progress notifications is one of the features of `TaskManager`.  See slide 48 of https://pocoproject.org/slides/130-Threads.pdf